# Get latest USN data from Change Journal

Tags: c++, winapi, logging, visual-c++, buffer

The MSDN C++ code only shows how to obtain the change journal records starting from the buffer.
[MSDN Code for Reading Change Journal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/walking-a-buffer-of-change-journal-records).

My query is how do I fetch just the latest USN records from Change journal. I've increased the buffer size to my requirement. 
`#define BUF_LEN 789824`
Also, I cannot set the buffer to the maximum size as it violates the DWORD max size limit.

The command `fsutils usn readjournal c:` takes a lot of time to show the output. So, how do I fetch only the latest records from the journal using c++?

Comment: I'm curious, what's this *"CHAR max size limit"*?

Comment: Corrected. DWORD upper limit** (4294967295)

Comment: Curious, still, how does setting a value to its maximum size violate its max size limit?

Comment: If I change the buffer size to 1179648 i.e. (double the previous value), it shows an exception showing that '''Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF6A35F7888 in deletesoon.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000735F603000). occurred'''

Comment: That's not the size limit of a `DWORD`, though. You have simply run out of stack space. Why are you allocating huge chunks of memory on the stack?

Comment: Basically showing, '''Error reading characters of the string''' for Buffer. And when I expand  the buffer array elements in locals window, it shows '''Unable to read memory'''

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215081/discussion-between-priyalsoni-and-iinspectable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a large buffer leads to large memory allocation, which in turn leads to performance degradation. A workaround for this is to keep `#define BUF_LEN 4096` (a small value) and increase the value of iterations to the maximum size of the change journal.

```
for (I = 0; I <= 2415919104; I++)
```

Here, the large value is simply the output returned by `fsutil usn queryjournal C:` (or any NTFS journal). `Maximum Size     : 0x0000000090000000`. (Convert hex value to decimal value)

This worked for me. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Don't forget to mark your own answer. This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread in the future.

Comment: Surely, I'll do that. 1 day to go.